# http outbound gateway PUT request 400 Bad Request [No Body]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

[image]    <int:chain id="re-t-ob-chain" input-channel="testIntmChannel" output-channel="outputChannel">
<int:service-activator ref="testTransformer" method="preprocessRequest"/>
int:header-enricher
<int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/xml"/>
<int:header name="Accept" value="application/json"/>
</int:header-enricher>
<int-http:outbound-gateway
id="testOutboundGateway"
url-expression="headers.testUrl"
http-method="PUT"
request-factory="testRequestFactory"
extract-request-payload="true"
charset="UTF-8"
mapped-request-headers="Content-Type,Accept"
expected-response-type="com.test.integration.TestResponse">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>

getting 400 Bad Request[No Body] for PUT http request call, payload is not getting passed to outbound gateway even though I see message.payload has expected request object in preprocessRequest. Request payload is in xml format.

```
<bean id="testRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="readTimeout"    value="10000"/>
</bean>

<int-http:inbound-gateway
     request-channel="rTRequestChannel"
     reply-channel="rTReplyChannel"
     supported-methods="PUT"
     path="/test/activities"
     mapped-request-headers="*"
     request-payload-type="com.test.integration.request. SampleRequest">
     </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

Request class:

```
@XmlType(name="users")
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
public class SampleRequest implements Serializable{

    private List<User> users;

    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=true, name="User")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public SampleRequest(){

    }
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: What does your `preprocessRequest` return for downstream flow? What is your `testRequestFactory`? It would be great if you can debug your solution to see what really comes to the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange()` as a content of the `httpRequest` parameter.

Comment: preprocessRequest returns "return new GenericMessage<>((SampleRequest)message.getPayload(), headers);"  SampleRequest is a request class. I can't see httpRequest parameter in debug until before http outbound gateway is called, would you be able to tell when/how would I be able to see it? I added testRequestFactory above! thanks.

Comment: You set break point in that method and you perform a call for your flow. When message reaches that `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`, the debug will stop on that break point. From there you may follow down step by step to see where your `SampleRequest` is lost.

Comment: I can't figure out HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange it completely shows details like URI for other api used in our system, would there be any other way to see where SampleRequest is lost?

Comment: I only see the way to debug it through Spring API. You can also use a TRACE level for the `org.springframework.web.client` category to obtain some clues from logs. Other way is to share with me a simple project, so I can debug it for you.

Comment: sure, thank you for offering help! I have added inbound gateway details and Request class here! do you think it might have anything to do with xml request instead of json? do I need to add anything extra like converter etc. ?

Comment: The `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` relies on a default `RestTemplate`, where a `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` is used if JAXB is present in classpath and content type is an `application/xml`. So, your `SampleRequest` should be marshalled properly. There is nothing to do with a server side since you cannot reach it yet with that `400 Bad Request[No Body]`. Therefore would be great if can debug it down there or share with me a simple project to reproduce and play with.

Comment: thanks for you response! let me show you one more thing before I share a project with you, I have added a picture above, restTemplate uses above 7 message converters but i don't see the one you mentioned, Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter. My request payload is application/xml and response can contain application/xml or application/json. I captured it in debug.

Comment: Strange. How then `@XmlRootElement` works for you if there is no JAXB in your classpath?

Comment: I see these 2 jars on my classpath, javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1 and jaxb-api:jaxb-api:2.1 and also org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.6 and org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.6

Comment: What version of Spring do you use?

Comment: we use org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.7.1, org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:5.5.13

Comment: OK. Then I'd like to play with the project which can reproduce the issue.